# Select recent activity by user example post topic, comment topic, like topic order by time

Tags: mysql, join

So far I got this

```
select user_id,topic_id
from
( select u.user_id, t.topic_id from `user` u inner join `topic` t on t.topic_by =u.user_id 
union 
select u.user_id, c.comment_topic from `user` u inner join `comment` c on c.comment_by=u.user_id
union 
select u.user_id,th.thanks_by from `user` u inner join `thanks` th on th.thanks_by=u.user_id 
)x
where x.user_id=33
```

But the result is only user_id and topic_id I want to know the user action on that topic example user comment on topic A, user like topic B, user post topic C
and order by time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this......

```
SELECT u.user_id, t.topic_id, c.comment_topic, th.thanks_by
from user u
LEFT JOIN topic t ON t.topic_by =u.user_id
LEFT JOIN `comment` c on c.comment_by=u.user_id
LEFT JOIN `thanks` th on th.thanks_by=u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 33
GROUP BY u.user_id, t.topic_id, c.comment_topic, th.thanks_by
```

Comment: @AnhAnh plz check wheather comment & thanks table has data for user_id = 33

Comment: yes try other user_id it show but I got a lot of duplicate row.

Comment: @AnhAnh can you give an example